# Updating value in column

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to update some information on a column called Value:

```
Value Home
12     123
30     124
21     124
21     99
```

I would like to add to Value 0.5 if Home has value 124. I am thinking of using .loc to select rows but I would need to understand how to update the value. My expected results should be

```
Value Home
12     123
30.5   124
21.5   124
21     99
```

Any tip is appreciated.

Comment: `df['Value'] = np.where(df['Home'] == 124, df['Value'] + 0.5, df['Value'])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['Home']==124, 'Value'] += .5
```

Comment: thank you to both. May I ask you if this solution works also with another condition based on a different column (for example if Property is > 20)?

Comment: @still_learning sure: `df.loc[(df['Home']==124) & (df['Property'] > 20), 'Value']+=5`

Answer (score 2):

Use mask

```
mask = (df.Home == 124)
df.loc[mask,'Value'] = df.loc[mask,'Value'] + 0.5
```